# Jenkins Load Error

Tags: jenkins

I am new to jenkins and I recently installed jenkins on my local system. When the installation was complete and the Jenkins Dashboard had to load, I got the error as in the snapshot attached.

The system is connected to VPN as its office system.

Kindly let me know what changes I should make to get jenkins up and running.

I checked the log file of jenkins and found that jenkins service abruptly ending because of jetty issue as below:

```html
SEVERE: Container startup failed
java.io.IOException: Failed to start Jetty
 at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:156)
 at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:354)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at Main._main(Main.java:294)
 at Main.main(Main.java:132)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
 at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:298)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:431)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
 at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:154)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot reach your local system? I don't get it.. Sorry, this question is very unclear to me.

Comment: Well, your question provides very little information about the issue that you are facing, but from what I can comprehend this looks like a network issue. You might want to check this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/this-site-cant-be-reached-the-connection-was-reset/7de48ad8-0157-44fb-aaf1-6119cc458d98?auth=1

Comment: I have updated the issue..

Comment: @ShrinivasJoshi `ava.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind` means that something else is already listening on the port it tries to listen to. Are you sure that you cleanly shut down all previous instances and nothing else listens on the same port?

Comment: @PeterT I have reinstalled the Jenkins after killing and validating that no listeners are active on the same port. It's working fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: In which machine you have installed Jenkins, Windows/Linux. Try with assigning different PORT number for running the Jenkins.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar thank you